# Android Threads and Open GL

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, touch-event

When I touch the surface of an android device a thread calls the onTouchEvent method. From traditional standpoints in Android, no rendering can take place till that thread completes what we write in the onTouchEvent. (Similar to Java's EDT if I am not mistaken.) My question is, because the OpenGL has a drawFrame(GL10 gl) method that is called everytime OpenGL can render a frame, can you "lock up" the onTouchEvent method and still get up-to-date rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`GLSurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) documentation has the answer:

> Renders on a dedicated thread to decouple rendering performance from
>   the UI thread.

Since the `onTouchEvent` is handled on the UI thread, the GL thread will happily keep going. Of course you will get the standard [application not responding](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) dialog when you lock up the UI thread for too long.